# Spark: Different output with different number of cores

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark, cpu-cores

I'm dealing with a strange behaviour when I change the number of cores in my Spark Application and here is the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
object Test extends App {
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
var listLink: List[String] = List()
def addListLink(s: String) = {
val list = s.split(",")
for (i <- 0 to list.length - 2) {
  listLink = list(i)+ "-" + list(i + 1) :: listLink
 }
}
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val paths = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/percorsi.txt")
paths.foreach(x => addListLink(x))
println("Number of items:"+listLink.size)
println(listLink)
}
```

My input file is something like this:

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C
A,B,C
A,B,C
A,B,C
A,B,C
B,C,D
B,C,D
B,C,D
B,C,D
C,D
C,D
```

Basically for every path I call my method which adds an element to a List representing every consecutive couple of elements:

example : "A,B,C,D" => ("A-B","B-C","C-D")

As you can see, in the code there is just one core

```
.setMaster("local[1]")
```

And if I run my application (locally or on cluster) I get what I expect

```
println("Number of items:"+listLink.size)
//Result --> Number of Items : 38
```

If I change the number of cores to 3 (for example) I get different values.
For example 33 items instead of 38.

Am I missing something regarding the number of cores or something else (partitions, ecc...)?

I think this is quite a simple app, but I get this strange behaviour anyway.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

FF

Comment: why are you using foreach on your RDD??? what are you trying to do?

Comment: for each element in my RDD, I want to call that method in order to increase my list

Comment: maybe you've heard of map reduce? no? `foreach`Executes an parameterless function for each data item.

Comment: yes indeed... As said, maybe I'm missing something, but can I ask you a more specific hint? I mean, is that a problem regarding just foreach-style?

Comment: ok that's first, but still not about the "style", secondly can you try to explain please what you are trying to do with the linklist function?

Comment: as said in the question, for every element of paths RDD (for example "A,B,C,D") I need to increase my linkList with the couples of consecutive letters in it (for example "A-B","B-C","C-D")... at the end of the App, listLink.size should be 38, but changing the number of cores from 1 to N (with N > 1) I get a different value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78452/discussion-between-eliasah-and-panto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a separate `listLink` per partition. So you're adding items to several lists, and only one gets printed at the end.

> Normally, when a function passed to a Spark operation (such as map or
>   reduce) is executed on a remote cluster node, it works on separate
>   copies of all the variables used in the function. These variables are
>   copied to each machine, and no updates to the variables on the remote
>   machine are propagated back to the driver program.

(from here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables)

It's your lucky day:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer


val data = List(
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C,D",
"A,B,C",
"A,B,C",
"A,B,C",
"A,B,C",
"A,B,C",
"B,C,D",
"B,C,D",
"B,C,D",
"B,C,D",
"C,D",
"C,D")

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
val sc= new SparkContext(conf)


val dataRDD = sc.makeRDD(data, 1)
val linkRDD = dataRDD.flatMap(_.split(",").sliding(2).map{_.mkString("", "-", "")})

linkRDD.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
C-D
A-B
B-C
A-B
B-C
A-B
B-C
A-B
B-C
A-B
B-C
B-C
C-D
B-C
C-D
B-C
C-D
B-C
C-D
C-D
C-D
```

Comment: thanks a lot Paul, that's more what I was guessing... I've totally forgotten shared variables... I'll take a look and see how to modify my code.

Comment: I'd like to have my "problem" solved (code included) before accepting your answer in order to help someone else with the same doubt

Comment: OK. In general, SO isn't a "please write my code" site. Also, producing a l list of links isn't the end goal, I assume. Please describe what you want to calculate, because there's probably a more Spark-ish way of doing it. As @eliasah has also requested.

Comment: Thanks again Paul... As said in my first comment to your answer, I'd have tried to improve my code asap (since I'm not in front of my PC). I know that SO is not a "write my code". Anyway, since you wrote it, I thank you once again.

Comment: And BTW your spark-ish solution is definetly cleaner :-)

Comment: Great answer Paul! That's why I was trying to understand what he is trying to accomplish. I knew it was a shared variable issue

Comment: @Paul: since I'm investigating broadcast variable in order to understand'em better, may I ask you some advices regarding my question... Even though I'm using broadcast variable, I'm stuck with the same "core problems"

Comment: I've never used broadcast variables (never needed to). But broadcast variables are read only so if you're using them to keep your list of items, you're doing it wrong. You might use an accumulator, but  you shouldn't use that for a collection, especially one that's the same size or bigger than your RDD. RDDs are meant for distributed collections, so use them for that!

Comment: Thanks for the advice... The fact is that, even it's not so spark oriented,I'm trying to solve my initial problem (with my code, not yours) adding accumulators, but actually I can't get what I need: I always get "partial" results due to different partition, even though I'm following accumultors way as suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377182/spark-create-new-accumulator-type-wont-work-scala)

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this"/"Don't do that, then".